# DELPHI/TComport with UAC/uiAccess only fails to read/write to device with TComPort2010

Tags: windows, delphi, uac, tcomport

I have a Delphi desktop application that uses TComport2010 to perform USB/COM communications. This application, read coords X,Y from USB device and poke on windows desktop simulating mouse. All works fine, except when try to move the window of OSK(on screen keyboard), this issue is fixed with application running with administrator rights or `uiAccess = true` on manifest, see discussion here: [OSK access problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454538/access-oskon-screen-keyboard-handle-from-desktop-app-without-administrator-rig?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Well following solution suggested in above post, I can poke mouse events on OSK.
But, the TComport2010 fails to write on comport when running the app with the follow manifest, that have only request `uiAccess = true`, and not superuser rights.

```
<requestedPrivileges>
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>
</requestedPrivileges>
```

The app is compiled with manifest suggested, is signated and running on program file dir, but, in this situation, comport fails, cant write... if I run the application with context menu run as administrator, then all works fine, OSK pokes and com port read/write.
The app need some kind of rights to access COM devices ? Or maybe related to registry access of TComport ?
The full manifest is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    name="pendrv.exe"
    version="2.0.0.2552"
    processorArchitecture="*" />
  <description>Fixed Up App</description>   
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"    
        processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application> 
        <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 7 functionality-->
          <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 8 functionality-->
          <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 8.1 functionality-->
          <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      </application> 
  </compatibility>  
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>

      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet ID="FullTrust" Unrestricted="true" />
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="FullTrust" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>

      <requestedPrivileges>
        <!-- this access OSK but tcomport fails -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>

        <!-- in this case all works fine, but popup superuser request, that I want to avoid -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/> 
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Well, the problem is why TcomPort don't work with manifest using only `uiAccess = true`, like this:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>
```

I running app signated and in the program files folder.

The delhpi code that fails is the call to writestr on comport, this fails when running the app with asinvoker and uiaccess=true, when run with administrator right it works, if I put the app without manifest and any rights on the same folder all the com job works too. The pertinent delphi code follows:

The com component dont rises any message sended by the device, I sure that device send a msg in each 30seconds, but the onrxchar event never rises, the write function is called but not sure if msg is really send to device. In general words, seems that windows block communication between device and delphi component whe running with asinvoker and uiaccess=true. If I run with admin rights, the same code works perfectly.

I put the code of tcomport on pastebin because here have size limitations, the link of code is:

> > [source code of TComPort](http://pastebin.com/RK3sshQV)

After put some log messages writed to a memo field, I trace the normal cicle of TComport events when receive some data from external usb device.

This is the cycle of normal read/receive data operation: (running as admnistrator)

```
TCOMLOG:-----CreateHandle OK-----
TCOMLOG:_WriteStrWrapper:<read_ch>=9
TCOMLOG:Thread.DispathComMsg
TCOMLOG:Thread.DoEvents
TCOMLOG:DoTxEmpty
TCOMLOG:Thread.execute
TCOMLOG:Thread.DispathComMsg
TCOMLOG:Thread.DoEvents
TCOMLOG:CallRxChar
TCOMLOG:DoRxChar call
TCOMLOG:ReadStr called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync passed
TCOMLOG:ReadStr finished
TCOMLOG:Thread.execute
TCOMLOG:Thread.DispathComMsg
TCOMLOG:Thread.DoEvents
TCOMLOG:CallRxChar
TCOMLOG:DoRxChar call
TCOMLOG:ReadStr called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync passed
TCOMLOG:ReadStr finished
TCOMLOG:Thread.execute
TCOMLOG:Thread.DispathComMsg
TCOMLOG:Thread.DoEvents
TCOMLOG:CallRxChar
TCOMLOG:DoRxChar call
TCOMLOG:ReadStr called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync passed
TCOMLOG:ReadStr finished
TCOMLOG:Thread.execute
...
```

Here is the cycle when I run the app with only uiAccess=true and asInvoker level, in the same program files folder of windows:

```
TCOMLOG:-----CreateHandle OK-----
TCOMLOG:_WriteStrWrapper:<read_ch>=9
TCOMLOG:Thread.DispathComMsg
TCOMLOG:Thread.DoEvents
TCOMLOG:DoTxEmpty
TCOMLOG:Thread.execute
TCOMLOG:Thread.DispathComMsg
TCOMLOG:Thread.DoEvents
TCOMLOG:CallRxChar
TCOMLOG:DoRxChar call
TCOMLOG:ReadStr called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync called
TCOMLOG:ReadAsync passed
TCOMLOG:ReadStr
```

The log stops on ReadStr, seems that thread.execute freeze or something, maybe for unknow reason the APP dont receive usb events from windows..

Comment: Accessing a COM port doesn't require any special privileges. It may be something that either you do in your code or TComPort does that prevents `asInvoker` and raises the requirement for admin level. How does TComPort fail? Error message? You need to debug your application to find the line where the failure happens, if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: Well, the event onafterconnect raises, the event onrxchar raises too, but when try to make a writestr on com, it fails, dont raise any exception, I put the code inside a try/exception... WIth this settings in manifest I cant debug

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that cause any exception. Also post relevant code that `just fails`. I repeat my question: *what exception / error do you see? How does writing fail?*. You need to be verbose about these things, if you ask for help.

Comment: I don't understand why you first added some code and then removed it again? Anyway I see that you log some error situations. **Is that log written to disk?** And specifically to the same directory as where your program is?

Comment: The code has bigger size that post permit, I share the code via the paste bin now.

Comment: You still haven't answered the latest questions in my previous comment.

Comment: We seem to have a communication problem. This is my last attempt: Does your program write to any file in the same directory where the program is located? I ask because if it is, then that is the reason. A program is not allowed to write to the Program Files directory unless it is run as administrator.

Comment: Nope, the program dont write any file while running, all log is on memo fields. When I compile the program WITHOUT the .RC of manifest listed, the program works fine with COM events on the same "program files" dir WITHOUT administrator rights.

Comment: Thank you for answer, ok, one reason cancelled out. I downloaded the same TComPort, made a test app, and it runs ok in `program files`. However, my setup is not the same as yours because I dont have a device to test with. Instead I use com0com and two ComPort components that communicate with eachother. As manifest I used your with `asInvoker` enabled. So, I can not replicate your problem. The only way I see is that you debug it to find out why and where the communication fails. See `Run - Load process` and the `Help` on that page for how to do. You also need to build with `Map file` enabled.

Comment: Well man, thanks for you help. After days of tests and all fails, I seek for a new COM component, and find the nrComLib  http://www.deepsoftware.com/nrcomm/index.html, that works fine on related scenario. I will adopt this lib, and buy that. On tests with trial version and manifest with only asinvoker and uiAccess=true, we can have full control over OSK with we hard device on usb. Thanks a lot. The problem is related to TComPort, but I can not find what is.